# Trouble printing list items in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

So dictionary is as follows for example.

```
test = {'T1':['testone','testprize']}
```

`print(key,'test is'`, then print just testone followed by,`'you win'`,then print the testprize

Answer (score 0):

You want to index through the list of values in the dictionary:

```
print (key, 'test is', test[key][0], 'you win', test[key][1])
```

Though, as written, this won't get the key directly. The key has to be specified somehow.

Since you haven't shown any other code, I don't know whether the key is specified somewhere else in your script.

For example, earlier in the script there may be a specification of `for key in dict:` that loops through the dictionary entries, or the specific dict entry is specified in some other way, like `key = 'T1'`.

You'll have to provide more info if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Im actually working on homework and thought that the key would be T1 in the example given. was my understanding that the key is whatever comes before the :.

Comment: This also worked perfectly for what I have been working on thank you very much. I was close but my formatting was off.

Comment: the key is 'T1', but it needs to be assigned to a variable before it can be printed (or otherwise manipulated). The loop of 'for key in dict' does the job of assigning the variable 'key' to each key in the dictionary, so that you can then specify 'key' in your print statement.

Comment: But if i were trying to make a for loop to list say T1-T12 with that simple print statement it would work. I think you are getting into more technical areas where if I wanted to list every odd key or something of that matter it might need to have a variable.

Comment: Alternate approach with `str.format` operators to avoid indexing (not worth separate answer): `print(key, 'test is {} you win {}'.format(*test[key]))`